# Templated optional argument constructor with void parameter callback

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm looking to write a class such than it can store a piece of data and pass it through a lambda. I'd also like to be able to have an option to not pass a value in the constructor and have the constructor generate with a lambda without a parameter. I'm OK, with still having a piece of data on the class.

I've tried using optionals and using a default template parameter of type void but couldn't get it to work. The closest thing I got was this.

```
template<class T = void>
class X {
   std::optional<T> d;       // data present or garbage data
   std::function<void(T)> f; // parameter = type of data or void if no arg provided
public:
   X(std::optional<T> a, std::function<void(T)> b) : d{a}, f{b} {}
   a() {
      if (d.has_value()) f(d);
      else f();
   }
}
```

Hoping the constructor work like

```
X(5, [&](int x) {}); // where the int type is implied from the constructor
```

OR

```
X([&](){}); // where the lack of parameter implies the function parameter is void
```

Thank you.

EDIT: provided an example of an attempt to generate the class myself
EDIT 2: attempted to clarified the need to store and call the function at a later date.

Comment: Can you provide us in detail what you have so far and what you want to achieve, input and output?

Comment: A function `void(int)` differs from `void ()`. Maybe just use `std::function<void(std::optional<T>)>`? Or pass two functions - one to `void(T)` and another to `void()`? Your model makes no sense to me, are you trying to reimplement `std::bind`? `std::optional<void>` doesn't make sense, maybe just overfload template on `void` and non-`void`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make bind work. Optional<T> in the function call works alright but seems a little odd. In the case of No parameters, what would I use as the default template value to get it to function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "void foo()" << std::endl;
}

void bar(int x) {
    std::cout << "void foo(int x) with parameter x = " << x << std::endl;
}

class X {
public:
    template <typename F, typename ... Args>
    X(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
        std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main() {
    X a(foo);
    X b(bar, 1);
    X c([&](int x, int y) {
        std::cout << "lambda with parameters x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    }, 1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Check [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:28,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:28,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:28,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:28),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22void+foo()%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+bar(int+x)+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22void+foo(int+x)+with+parameter+x+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+x+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass+X+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+F,+typename+...+Args%3E%0A++++X(F%26%26+f,+Args%26%26...+args)+%7B%0A++++++++std::invoke(std::forward%3CF%3E(f),+std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++X+a(foo)%3B%0A++++X+b(bar,+1)%3B%0A++++X+c(%5B%26%5D(int+x,+int+y)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22lambda+with+parameters+x+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+x+%3C%3C+%22+y+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+y+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D,+1,+2)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.882506527415146,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:53.74289633548893,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.117493472584854,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Basically, by using provided class `X` you can send whatever function you want (free function, lambda, etc.) and pass any number of parameters you want.

**UPDATE**

According to the OP's comment and wish to store the lambda and arguments to a class member and call it later, here is the updated code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
class X {
public:
    X(F&& f, Args&&... args)
        : f_(std::forward<F>(f)),
          args_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    void call() {
        std::apply(f_, args_);
    }

private:
    F f_;
    std::tuple<Args...> args_;
};

int main() {
    X c([&](int x, int y) {
        std::cout << "lambda with parameters x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    }, 1, 2);

    c.call();

    return 0;
}
```

Check [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:6,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:6,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:6,startLineNumber:15),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+F,+typename+...+Args%3E%0Aclass+X+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++X(F%26%26+f,+Args%26%26...+args)%0A++++++++:+f_(std::forward%3CF%3E(f)),%0A++++++++++args_(std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%0A++++void+call()+%7B%0A++++++++std::apply(f_,+args_)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0Aprivate:%0A++++F+f_%3B%0A++++std::tuple%3CArgs...%3E+args_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++X+c(%5B%26%5D(int+x,+int+y)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22lambda+with+parameters+x+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+x+%3C%3C+%22+y+%3D+%22+%3C%3C+y+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D,+1,+2)%3B%0A%0A++++c.call()%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.882506527415146,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:53.74289633548893,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.117493472584854,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: Very close, I'm trying to get you're solution to work such that I can store and use the function for later with only 1 or 0 args. My apologies for not clarify this point.

Comment: @user3786992 i have updated the answer. Please check it out and accept and upvote if it helped you, or comment if you have more questions